# Angular.js filter to display same values from JSON data

Tags: angularjs

This is my code, I'm trying to render a list of items should contain "type_transaction" is equal to "paypal" and im trying to avoid rendering different than "paypal".

DATA in JSON:

```
    {
        "orders":[
            {
                "id_order":"374",
                "type_transaction":"paypal"
            },
            {
                "id_order":"373",
                "type_transaction":"credit-card"
            },
            {
                "id_order":"372",
                "type_transaction":"credit-card"
            },
            {
                "id_order":"371",
                "type_transaction":"paypal"
            }

        ]
   }
```

HTML:

```
                    <tbody ng-init="get_orders()">
                        <tr ng-repeat="order in orders | filter:searchText">
                            <td>{{order.id_order}}</td>
                            <td>{{order.type_transaction}}</td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
```

Javascript function will apply the filter to display a list according if their items are same to "Paypal":

```
$scope.get_orders = function(n) {

    $http.post(url, $scope.main ).success(function(data){
      $filter('filter')(data.orders, "'type_transaction': 'paypal'", true) = data.orders;
        //$scope.orders = data.orders;
    });
}
```

It gave me an error, it showed **ReferenceError: Invalid left-hand side in assignment**
I still don't understand how $filter works.

Comment: try with ng-if      in your html view

Comment: @amani92 Can you elaborate this? I tried to put ng-if="'type_transaction': 'paypal'" with ng-repeat, so it won't work

Comment: `$filter('filter')(...)=data.orders;` Your error is not about `$filter` - it's how javascript works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to surround string (paypal) with quotes ':

ng-if="order.type_transaction=='paypal'"